# Uniqueness of the scheme structure for a given Hilbert polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, flatness

If we have two lines in $P^3$ which are skewed, then we can take the union of those lines as a subscheme of $P^3$ in order to obtain a subscheme of $P^3$ with a Hilbert Polynomial given by $2m+2$.

Suppose you want to define a map from the product of the grasmannians $G(1,3)\times G(1,3)$ away from the diagonal to the component of the Hilbert scheme where the generic point is precisely two skew lines with the reduced structure. Then one possible flat limit is two different lines intersecting in a point and in order for the map to be defined there must be exactly one scheme structure that can be obtained  as a flat limit for this configuration.

More precisely, take $P^3$ with coordinate $x, y, z$ and $w$,  and a pair of skew lines  defined one by $<x,y>$ and the other one $L_t$ defined by $<z,y-tw>$ for $t\neq 0$, then the flat limit of the union of these two skewed lines as $t\to 0$ is a pair of reduced lines intersecting at a point, plus an embedded point at $[0:0:0:1]$ whose defining ideal is $<y,xz>\cap<x,y^2,z> $, and that once again gives us a subscheme of $P^3$ with Hilbert Polynomial $2m+2$.

My question is this: Is the given structure for this singular conic $<y,xz>$ in $P^3$ the only one we can obtain as a flat limit of skew lines? And if so why, and how general is this result?